# Disk usage for Europe (OpenStreetMap)

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, nominatim, europe

I would like to know a disk space usage for Europe extract (Nominatim, tile server, both data structures and rendered tiles). 
I have currently map server with an european country extract and I tried to estimate disk usage for Europe. My estimation is a very big number (about 1,3 - 1,4TB!).
Is it possible? Am i wrong? Can someone correct or confirm my estimation?

My calculation's ways are:

1. Europe surface to country surface ratio
2. Europe osm.pbf file to country osm.pbf file ratio

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/45982/disk-usage-for-europe-openstreetmap